# Merge lines and do operations if a condition is statisfied

Tags: perl, merge, sum, lines

I'm new in perl and I would like to read a table and make a sum of some values from specific lines. This is a simplified example of my input file:

INPUT :

```
Gene  Size Feature

GeneA 1200 Intron 1

GeneB 100  Intron 1

GeneB 200  Intron 1

GeneB 150  Intron 2

GeneC 300  Intron 5
```

OUTPUT :

```
GeneA 1200 Intron 1

GeneB 300  Intron 1 <-- the size values are summed 

GeneB 150  Intron 2

GeneC 300  Intron 5
```

---

Because Gene B is present for intron 1 with two different sizes, I would like to sum these two values and print only one line per intron number.

This is an example of code that I want to do. But I would like to make it more complicated if I can understand How to handle this kind of data.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $sum;
my @GAP_list;
my $prevline = 'na';
open INFILE,"Table.csv";
while (my $ligne = <INFILE>) 
  {
chomp ($ligne);
my @list = split /\t/, $ligne;

  my $gene= $list[0];   
  my $GAP_size= $list[2];  
  my $intron= $list[3];
  my $intron_number=$list[4];


  if($prevline eq 'na'){
  push @GAP_list, $GAP_size;
  }
  elsif($prevline ne 'na') {
  my @list_p = split /\t/,$prevline;
  my $gene_p= $list_p[0];   
  my $GAP_size_p= $list_p[2]; 
  my $intron_p= $list_p[3];
  my $intron_number_p=$list_p[4];
      if (($gene eq $gene_p) && ($intron eq $intron_p) && ($intron_number eq $intron_number_p)){
  push @GAP_list, $GAP_size;
       }
   }
  else{
  $sum = doSum(@GAP_list);
  print "$gene\tGAP\t$GAP_size\t$intron\t$intron_number\t$sum\n";
    $prevline=$ligne;

  }     

 }  

# Subroutine
sub doSum {
    my $sum = 0;
    foreach my $x (@_) { 
        $sum += $x; 
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

Comment: Soo, loop with a buffer of one line; if they are different, print the old line and store the current line; if they are equal, add the current line to the stored value? How are the parts seperated? By tab, or does each line match the regex `/^(\w+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+(.+)$/`?

Comment: Thanks amon for your help ! the values are seprated with tab(\t). But I would like a perl logic to do that, because I would like do did other operations using perl and the original data contain more than 65 coloumn;

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the fields are seperated by tabs, then the following strategy would work. It buffers the last line, either adding up if the other fields are equal, or printing the old data and then replacing the buffer with the current line.

After the whole input was processed, we must not forget to print out the contents that are still in the buffer.

```
my $first_line = do { my $l = <>; chomp $l; $l };
my ($last_gene, $last_tow, $last_intron) = split /\t/, $first_line;

while(<>) {
  chomp;
  my ($gene, $tow, $intron) = split /\t/;
  if ($gene eq $last_gene and $intron eq $last_intron) {
    $last_tow += $tow;
  } else {
    print join("\t", $last_gene, $last_tow, $last_intron), "\n";
    ($last_gene, $last_tow, $last_intron) = ($gene, $tow, $intron);
  }
}

print join("\t", $last_gene, $last_tow, $last_intron), "\n";
```

This works fine as long as genes that may be folded together are always consecutive. If the joinable records are spread all over the file, we have to keep a data structure of all records. After the whole file is parsed, we can emit nicely sorted sums.

We will use a multilevel hash that uses the gene as first level key, and the intron as 2nd level key. The value is the count/tow/whatever:

```
my %records;

# parse the file
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my ($gene, $tow, $intron) = split /\t/;
  $records{$gene}{$intron} += $tow;
}

# emit the data:
for my $gene (sort keys %records) {
  for my $intron (sort keys %{ $records{$gene} }) {
    print join("\t", $gene, records{$gene}{$intron}, $intron), \n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like something that can be done easily using a simple **SQL Query**. Especially as you get your files in a database table format. I couldn't comment on your question, to ask you more about it as I don't have enough reputation to do so.

So I'm assuming that you get your data from a table. Not that you can't solve this problem in Perl. But I strongly recommend using the database to do such calculation when fetching the data file, as that seems much easier. And I am not sure why you chose to do it in Perl, especially when you have lots of such fields in a file and you wanted to do such operations on all of them. And you could still use Perl to interact with your database when solving your problem via an SQL Query.

So my proposed solution in SQL, if the data is collected from a database is:
Write an SQL statement involving a GROUP BY on the GENE and feature field and aggregate the size column.
If your table looked exactly like what you described, let us call it GeneInformation table and you loaded your data file to the SQL database (SQLLite maybe) then your select query would be:

```
SELECT gene, feature, SUM(size) FROM GeneInformation 
 GROUP 
    BY gene, feature;
```

That should give you a list of genes, features and their corresponding total sizes .

**If SQL solution is completely impossible for you then I will talk about the Perl solution.** 
I noticed that the Perl solutions are based on the assumption that a particular gene's values would appear consecutively in the file. If that is the case then I would like to up vote [amon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1521179/amon)'s answer (which I can't do at the moment).